# What does ::class means in PHP?

Tags: php

I was looking at some code from Laravel, and I saw this:

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);
```

I found it very curious, because it seems to be calling a object method, but what is being passed doesn't look like a variable.

What is this `::class` thing?

Comment: [PHP 5.5 Classname Resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24461919)

Comment: Does it have a *raison d'etre*? Wouldn't it be the easier to use `$app->singleton("Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel", "App\Http\Kernel");` ?

Comment: It can deobfuscate aliased class/namespace imports. (Albeit in practice it's indeed often just used as syntax gimmick.)